# SQL: Combine TWO selects in ONE complex Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty complex query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM element_skanning yt1
            JOIN (SELECT objekt_nr, element_nr, vart
                FROM element_skanning
                GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr, vart
                HAVING count(*) > 1)
            yt2 ON (yt2.objekt_nr=yt1.objekt_nr AND yt2.element_nr=yt1.element_nr AND yt2.vart=yt1.vart)
            ORDER BY 2";
```

This is how my db looks like:

```
id     objekt_nr     element_nr     vart
-----------------------------------------
 1         1              1          Blå
 2         1              1          Blå
 3         1              1          Rosa
 4         1              1          Kont
 5         2              1          Rosa
 6         2              2          Blå
```

My excisting query will give me result: 1&2 because i use three inputs.

Now i´d like to search for a third dupe. Id: 3
How can i get result of id: 1,2,3 but not 4, 5 and 6?
The check should be if there is an row with same obj_nr & el_nr but "blå" or "Rosa" "vart" before.
So, Id 3 will be a dupe because of id: 1 & 2.
Id: 2, will be a dupe because of 1 & 3.
Id: 1, will be a dupe because of 2 & 3.

I did rewrite this a couple of times, i guess that´s why i can´t write the query.
 I hope you can understand what i want here?!
And how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM element_skanning yt1 JOIN
     (SELECT objekt_nr, element_nr
      FROM element_skanning
      WHERE vart IN ('blå', 'Rosa')
      GROUP BY objekt_nr, element_nr
      HAVING count(*) > 1
     ) yt2
      ON yt2.objekt_nr = yt1.objekt_nr AND
         yt2.element_nr = yt1.element_nr 
WHERE vart IN ('blå', 'Rosa')
ORDER BY 2;
```

Comment: Looks good, and runs. But i only got dupes if "vart" has two 'blå' entries. Not if one is 'blå' and one is 'rosa' but has same obj&el_nr...

Comment: Can it be this row who´s wrong: yt2.vart = yt1.vart  ?

Comment: @Mjukis . . . I think there was some wishful coding there.  I knew what I wanted it to do, but it cannot both `join` on `vart` and test for duplicates without `vart`.  So, the modification should fix this problem.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm!! Thank you very much! I could never figure this one out!